# mod_rewrite URL rewriting with or without Slash

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What is the correct way to write out the .htacess so that both www.domain.com/about_us and www.domain.com/about_us/ goes to www.domain.com/about_us.php

Currently, what I have is the below and just wonder if there's a way to put it in one line

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(about)$ /about_us.php
RewriteRule ^(about/)$ /about_us.php

Answer (score 3):

It's a regular expression, so adding ? after the / will make the / optional (0 or 1 occurrences).  Also, the parenthesis are unnecessary:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /about_us.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /about_us.php
```